# Is there an open source Java package that has classes representing HTMLElements?

Tags: java, html

I've noticed that the W3C publishes a set of Java interfaces around HTML elements, but I'm looking for implementations.  Apache has HttpComponents, but those are for Http requests, whereas I need classes to wrap HTML elements.  Anyone know of a package that will do this for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Apache Element Construction Set](http://jakarta.apache.org/ecs/index.html) does this. But I fear it may be a little out of date.

Answer (score 2):

Well, `Node`s in a 'standard' Java `org.w3c.dom.Document` can represent HTML elements, if you parse a HTML document into a Document.

What exactly should these classes be able to do for you?

Comment: I just want to use these objects as models of HTML elements, so anything that implements the standard getters and setters, would be great.

Answer (score 0):

[htmlunit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/index.html) does contain classes for html elements, e.g [HtmlAddress](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/html/HtmlAddress.html).